# Flash/Flex: Is it possible to encode Dictionary using AMF?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, amf

As the title suggests, is it possible to use AMF to encode/decode Dictionaries (without subclassing, that is)?

For example, here's a test case:

```
function serializeAndReload(obj:*):* {
    var serialized:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    serialized.writeObject(obj);
    serialized.position = 0;
    return serialized.readObject();
}

function test():void {
    var d:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    d[{}] = 42;
    d[d] = true;
    var x:* = serializeAndReload(d); // <<< x is an instance of Object
    trace(x['[object Object]']); // <<< traces '42'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be over-thinking. I use Object instead of Dictionary and it is automatically encoded using AMF. I use pyamf all the time to pass Objects/dicts around and its always worked without any mental effort on my part. Never have I needed to manually serialize/deserialize anything

Comment: It's true that Objects work nicely - but the Dictionary class is different from Object. Objects can only have Strings as keys, while Dictionaries can have any object.

Answer (score 0):

The keys in the `Dictionary` need to be serializable, too.

```
[RemoteClass(alias="Foo")]
public class Foo
{
}
```

Test:

```
var d:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
var f:Foo = new Foo();
d[f] = "Hello";
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba.writeObject(d);
ba.position = 0;
var d2:Dictionary = Dictionary(ba.readObject());
for (var key:* in d2)
{
    trace(getQualifiedClassName(key));
    trace(d2[key]);
}
```

Output:

```
Foo
Hello
```

Comment: uuhh… I'm not sure where you've tested this, but when I run it, the line `var d2:Dictioanry = …` raises a `TypeError` because `ba.readObject()` returns an `Object`, not a `Dictionary`.